# Why I'm not getting the 'trails' of the shutter drag photos?

Tags: long-exposure, second-curtain

I recently tried to do some shutter drag photography.
 I'm limited to the first curtain sync only, and it's not possible to use an external flash since it's a compact camera, or to trigger a flash since I don't have one with me.

Though I get a result that is satisfying to some level, I'm not getting the result I expected.

[image]

I only get a double exposure (?) image, without that trail, like 
[this one](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8515/8473599770_e379e66da6_z.jpg)?

My settings were

```
Shutter value - 8 sec
Aperture      - f7.3 (lowest I can go)
ISO           - 100 (lowest I can go)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

I would imagine that the transition between point A (standing there) and point B (close-up) was too fast. A good indicator of this is that you waited for some seconds at point A and then quickly moved to point B to again stand still for some seconds; **try to move continually, only stand still at points that should be articulated**.

As [Ian Lelsie](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20973) points out in the comments, it would be best to **choose an exposure time that is just as long as your transition will take**: so if you want to have a clearly visible trail of yourself walking from the left to the right of the frame, and you know that this walk will take you around 4 seconds (in a decent walking speed), then you should choose an exposure time that is about the same (say: 5-6 seconds, perhaps longer if you want some "stationary ghosts" on the way or at the beginning/end).

Another tip, commented by [Robin](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/13908), is to **wear clothes that are brighter than your surroundings - or have surroundings that are darker than your clothes**. Also, you could use **less ambient light** and use some **light source that is pointed (only) towards you**. As light decays with increasing distance to its source, this would work best if the walls/surroundings are further away from you than they are in your picture above.

---

With a flash and a very dark room (which will not be convenient to get around), you could also do [non-photoshopped multiple exposures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_exposure). That said, it will be safer for you and your furniture to use Photoshop or GIMP and start composing it *if that is an option to you*.

Comment: And then use an exposure time that accommodates how long it takes to move from point A to point B (and the time that you want to stand still at the end points).

Comment: Also, wear light coloured clothes and have another light source pointed at you but not the walls.  Dark walls would work even better.

Comment: @IanLelsie I included your comment into my answer - along with a reference to you. Thanks!

Comment: @Robin I included your comment into my answer - along with a reference to you. Thanks!